Includegraphics doesn't work
I Had TexWork editor on my previous computer and It worked (I wrote many rapport, thesis, ...).
But now I reinstall it on my new computer and I can't use includegraphics anymore, (codes I did before doesn't work anymore).
My code:
\documentclass [a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\textsc{Laboratoire de simulation n4}}
\lfoot{\textsc{Made with \LaTeX}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\graphicspath{{C:\\Users\\Morar\\Desktop\\ECAM\\PCB\\Rapport\\Image}}

\geometry{
a4paper,
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=20mm,
}
\title{Rapport de projet PCB}
\author{Mora Leonardo R. - 23351}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Le Projet choisit du cours de PCB Design est un indicateur de surchauffe de T. K. Hareendran.\\
Un capteur LM35 permet de connaitre la température ambiante et le potentiomètre permet de placer la limite de température afin de sonner le buzzer quand le LM35 dépasse cette limite.

\includegraphics{Schematique.png}

%\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Schematique.png}


\section{Au coeur du schéma}

\end{document}

The error:

! Missing endcsname inserted.

let
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
?
! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
 ???
! LaTeX Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: reserved@e re...
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
?
LaTeX Warning: File `Schematique.png' not found on input line 45.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Schematique.png' not found: using draft setti
ng.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
?

I tried to reinstall it again, to put another Perl, to update and install every component, I saw every kind of problem in stackoverflow but it doesn't work.
If someone know what's the problem and how to resolve it?
Thank you.
I work on Window 11 64bits, I work with TexWorks editor / TexLive
The log file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.5.1)  2 MAY 2024 12:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Rapport.tex
(./Rapport.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count189
\c@section=\count190
\c@subsection=\count191
\c@subsubsection=\count192
\c@paragraph=\count193
\c@subparagraph=\count194
\c@figure=\count195
\c@table=\count196
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2024/04/20 v24.4 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count197
\U@D=\dimen141
\l@unhyphenated=\language89

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count198

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'canadian' set to \l@english
(babel)             (\language0). Reported on input line 102.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'australian' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language23). Reported on input line 105.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'newzealand' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language23). Reported on input line 108.
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for english
(babel)             from babel-en.ini. Reported on input line 11.
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2024/03/29 v3.1b Micro-typographical refinements (RS)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count199
)
\MT@toks=\toks20
\MT@tempbox=\box51
\MT@count=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \noprotrusionifhmode on input line 1061.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \leftprotrusion on input line 1062.
\MT@prot@toks=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rightprotrusion on input line 1081.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 1392.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen142
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 2013.
\MT@listname@count=\count267

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2024/03/29 v3.1b Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)

LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 902.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 902.
\MT@outer@space=\skip50
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2024/03/29 v3.1b microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count268
)
\@linkdim=\dimen143
\Hy@linkcounter=\count269
\Hy@pagecounter=\count270

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count271

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count272

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen144

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count273
\Field@Width=\dimen145
\Fld@charsize=\dimen146
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count274
\c@Item=\count275
\c@Hfootnote=\count276
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count277
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count278

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip51
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
\lst@mode=\count279
\lst@gtempboxa=\box52
\lst@token=\toks22
\lst@length=\count280
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen147
\lst@column=\count281
\lst@pos=\count282
\lst@lostspace=\dimen148
\lst@width=\dimen149
\lst@newlines=\count283
\lst@lineno=\count284
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen150

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstpatch.sty
File: lstpatch.sty 2024/03/11 1.10a (Carsten Heinz)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2024/03/11 1.10a (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count285
\lst@skipnumbers=\count286
\lst@framebox=\box53
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2024/03/11 1.10a listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2024/03/11 1.10a (Carsten Heinz)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count287
\Gm@cntv=\count288
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count289
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen151
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen154
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen155
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen156
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen157
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen158
\Gm@dimlist=\toks23
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen159
\Gin@req@width=\dimen160
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count290
\float@exts=\toks24
\float@box=\box54
\@float@everytoks=\toks25
\@floatcapt=\box55
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2024/04/23 v4.2 Extensive control of page headers and footers

\f@nch@headwidth=\skip52
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip53
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip54
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip55
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip56
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip57
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip58
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip59
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip60
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 36
.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-04-11 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count291
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
)
(./Rapport.aux)
\openout1 = `Rapport.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `item' on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `toc' on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `eqnum' on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `footnote' on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `verbatim' on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `alltext-nott'.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \showhyphens on input line 36.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 36.

(./Rapport.out) (./Rapport.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `Rapport.out'.

\c@lstlisting=\count292

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 483.69687pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 686.7347pt, 101.40665pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=483.69687pt
* \textheight=686.7347pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-52.36449pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=50.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count293
\scratchdimen=\dimen161
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count294
\nofMParguments=\count295
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count296
\MPscratchDim=\dimen162
\MPnumerator=\count297
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count298
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 3
9.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+lmm on input line 3
9.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 
39.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+lmex on input line 
39.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 39.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 39.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 39.

! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   let 
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
                                      
? 
! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
                ! LaTeX Error: let invalid in file name. Lost: reserved@e re...
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
                                      
? 

LaTeX Warning: File `Schematique.png' not found on input line 45.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Schematique.png' not found: using draft setti
ng.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.45 \includegraphics{Schematique.png}
                                      
? 
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmtt on input line 4
5.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd
File: t1lmtt.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `lmtt' (encoding: T1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
 [1

{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{c:/texlive/2024/
texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}] (./Rapport.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>
 ***********
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Rapport.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 6BB73B688E3525FD91E43029B215DD54;248.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14222 strings out of 474050
 225318 string characters out of 5746299
 1929754 words of memory out of 5000000
 36447 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 586982 words of font info for 71 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,6n,79p,1004b,461s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024
/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/t
ype1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr1
7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmtt10.pfb>
Output written on Rapport.pdf (1 page, 126169 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 48 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 34 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 4 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 16913 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 17280 (max. 10000000)


Can you show the first few lines of the .log file?

I guess you want \graphicspath{{C:/Users/Morar/Desktop/ECAM/PCB/Rapport/Image}}. With \\ you don't escape a backslash but, happily, TeX systems on Windows know how to substitute / with the backslash when querying the file system

I put the error log
@egreg I did that and it's working, but why on my other computer, this didn't work and now it work with /?
because I put // because it worked on my previous computer (also window 11 and 64bits

I'm not sure that using \\ for paths on Windows has ever worked.

I've Always used \ before bcause on my previous laptop it didn't work to use /,but maybe it's my os was wierd

No, \\  has never worked in includegraphics on any system.

Just to put / in stead of \\, I don't know why it was the opposite before,but know it's working, thanks to @egreg
(Yes I know it's was on documentation,But it didn't work on my old laptop with /)

Please do not suggest in an answer that \\  has ever worked in graphicspath. If you have a document where it works you must have had \renewcommand\\{/}  which would make this work but break every other use of \\ 
